# How to use 4 bytes to save the date in a mysql timestamp,two?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to know what i understand is it right tostore timestamp in mysql.
and i found that 6 bits can only store 64 years. Unix time start 19700101000000,add   64years = 2034year, but some people say that timestamp can be saved util 2038.
can somebody anwser me ?
not php save time in mysql.that's two different things.don't close my question lightly.

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595884/what-is-the-smallest-number-of-bytes-that-can-store-a-timestamp) answer your question?  The four-byte Unix epoch time will take you to Jan 19, 2038.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say date in your title but timestamp (with implied precision in seconds) in your question.  The two are different.

A count of seconds from 1970-01-01 stored in a signed integer taking 4 bytes will have a maximum value of 2147483648 (2**31).  This gives a maximum timestamp of 2038-01-19 03:14:08; this is the source of references to 2038 you may see.

As far as saving time in mysql goes, you should not worry about it.  Use a DATE column type for dates, and use a DATETIME (or TIMESTAMP, which has some slight differences) column type for timestamps, with precision in seconds or milliseconds or microseconds depending on what you will store in it.  Trying to do something else for more efficiency will likely just give you headaches and not any better performance.

Comment: Thank you for answering my doubts,I forgot the most basic things.I can't believe I used the year, month, day, hour, minute and second for timestamp,thank you very much